# Split string into array of words and numbers using Perl

Tags: perl, split

How can I split a string like "**aa132bc4253defg18**" to get an array of words and numbers:

- aa,132,bc,4253,defg,18

I´m using Perl. The lengths of the subtrings are variable.

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? We aren't here to write your code for you, you know :-)

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
use Modern::Perl;
use Data::Dump qw(dump);

my $str = "aa132bc4253defg18";
my @l = split(/(?<=\d)(?=\D)|(?<=\D)(?=\d)/, $str);
dump@l;
```

**Output:**

```
("aa", 132, "bc", 4253, "defg", 18)
```

It splits between a digit `\d` and a non digit `\D`, in both order.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will do:

```
split (/(\d+)/, $x);
```

With a full working example:

```
use strict; use warnings;

my $x = 'aa132bc4253defg18';

my @y = split /(\d+)/, $x;

print join ",", @y;
```

The important sections in [perldoc split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) are:

> Anything in EXPR that matches PATTERN is taken to be a separator that separates the EXPR into substrings (called "fields") that do not include the separator.

and

> If the PATTERN contains capturing groups, then for each separator, an additional field is produced for each substring captured by a group (in the order in which the groups are specified, as per backreferences);

**Edit**

If the string starts with a number, `split` will return an empty element. These can be elimanated with a `grep`:

```
grep {$_} split /(\d+)/, $x;
```

The example becomes

```
use strict; use warnings;

my $x = '44aa132bc4253defg18';

my @y = grep {$_} split /(\d+)/, $x;

print join ",", @y;
```

Comment: It´s ok, but when I split a string beginning with a number like "123abc", I´m getting an empty item at the start of the array. Can I avoid this?